# Disable Chef client interval runs

Tags: chef-infra

I want to disable the chef-client to run at interval. For time being I want to switch to running chef-client manually from the command line.

Purportedly this can be achieved by running the client with
`sudo chef-client --once`. This however is not/no longer the case.

The Chef client will keep on running with interval after running that command. Unfortunately.

What is the correct/another way to prevent the chef client fron running automatically?

Comment: What's your node's run list? Is there the [chef-client](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client) cookbook included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef does not ship anything that sets itself up as a daemon or any other kind of automatic run. You would have to have had configured this youself, usually via the chef-client cookbook. Unfortunately this cookbook does not seem to have uninstall/removal recipes so you would have to do it manually in whatever init system you are using.